# How to add information from PHP into a list inside of Python? (CodeIgniter, PHP 7, Python 3.4)

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, python-3.x, php-7

For instance, using the form helper, I create a view (we'll call it `form.php`) that allows the user to enter the word and then this passed to the controller (we'll call this `controller.php`). I also have a python file (we'll call it `listOfWords.py`) that currently consists of an empty list. What is the best way to go about importing the words entered from `form.php` to the list inside of `listOfWords.py`?

```
from textblob import TextBlob;
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier;
import sys;

def machineLearning(issue):
    train = [
        ('I cannot enter or exit the building','idCard'),
        ('Enter or exit', 'idCard'),
        ('Card needs replacing','idCard'),
        ('ID card not working','idCard'),
        ('Printing', 'printer'),
        ("My ID Card doesn't sign me into the printers", "printer"),
        ('Mono', "printer"),
        ('Colour Printing',"printer"),
        ('I cannot connect my phone to the wifi', 'byod'),
        ('I do not get emails on my phone, tablet, or laptop', 'byod'),
        ('Cannot send emails','email'),
        ('Do not recieve emails','email'),
        ('Cannot sign in to moodle', 'email'),
        ('Cannot sign in to computer','desktop_pc'),
        ("Software isn't working",'desktop_pc'),
        ('I cannot find my work', 'lost_work'),
        ('My work has been corrupted', 'lost_work'),
        ('My work has been lost', 'lost_work'),
        ('Coursework gone missing', 'lost_work')
    ];

    test = [
        ("My id card does not allow me to go through the gates, the light flashes orange and then goes red. The gate doesn't open", "idCard"),
        ('My id card has snapped', 'idCard'),
        ('When printing, swiping my ID card does not automatically sign me in, I have to manually register my card', 'printer'),
        ('I am getting errors when trying to sign into my email account on the website', 'email'),
        ('Microsoft applications were not working','desktop_pc'),
        ('Software is missing','desktop_pc'),
        ('software keeps crashing','desktop_pc'),
        ('my phone refuses to connect to the internet','byod'),
        ('I cannot sign in to the computers, moodle or emails because I have forgotten my password','desktop_pc'),
        ('I cannot get my emails on my device I bought from home','byod'),
        ('My ID card does not allow me to print. I go to scan my card on the printer, and it comes up with a message saying that I need to associate my card every day I want to print. Other peoples cards work fine?','idCard'),
        ('My password does not allow me to sign in to the computers, laptops, moodle or emails','forgotten_password'),
        ('I have forgotten my password','forgotten_poassword'),
    ];

    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train);

    print(cl.classify(issue));

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    machineLearning(sys.argv[1]);
```

Comment: What are you using listOfWords.py for? While there are many ways to accomplish this, the real question is why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @jardis I'm using it for a machine learning algorithm, in particular textblobs for python. This was the simplest algorithm to use and did a good enough job. The llist of words is actually the train in the format:

Comment: @jardis `list = ['sentence/word', 'category name']`. I was just trying to keep it simple for others that may need this question for different reasons, trying to generalise.

Comment: Does listOfWords.py only consist of this list? If so, why not just make this a JSON file, and let PHP read/write using json_decode and json_encode

Comment: @JayHewitt I've updated the code to include the listOfWords.py file (although its not actually called that - like I say, I was trying to generalise the question)

Comment: I completely agree with @JayHewitt, the simplest way is to write the words into a json string and then let python interact with the json file.